# Websphere connection pool issue

Tags: java, database-connection, connection-pooling, websphere-7

I added a new datasource to websphere V7.0 and it works fine, but after some inactivity time the pool will return dead connection, and java would go into waiting till connection timeout expired. The connection pool will work again if I go to datasource admin page and “Test connection”.

I noticed that our oracle db will close connections on its side time to time.

Do you know how to make the connection alive again from java? Is there another way to fight dead connections in Websphere pool?

Comment: I found "WebSphere Application Server data source properties" -> "Connection Validation properties". Based on my experience with other pools - it should help. Will play with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the network connection. I asked DBA to change SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME to 1 minute at Oracle DB and it helped to resolve the issue.

There is a firewall between the application server with connection pool and data base. It looks like the firewall would expire the link before the connection expires at the server.

I noticed similar behavior for Oracle and iSeries. In some cases it would help to change connection pool settings and verify connections in the pool on a regular basis. This type of change I made for Dynamo ATG connection pool when it tried to connect to iSeries.

Comment: note that 1 minute is a bit to often, but the period has to be lower than link settings at firewall